# Calculated SQL Server Trigger by Attribute?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am having trouble putting together a SQL Server trigger. The database consists of 3 tables, 1 with MLB players information including a column `Play_Salary`.

Another table is `Teams`, and contains team information such as name, location, and salary cap. I am trying to create a trigger than when executed would sum all of the players' salaries which are on the same team, and insert them into the `Team` table, under the column `Total_Player_Salary` (which is already created).

The issue I am struggling with is in the `players` table, they are not broken up into the team. So how do I tell SQL Server to only sum the salaries of the players from the same team, and insert it into the row for that team in the other table.

Here is what I have so far, though I think I'm using `GROUP BY` wrong:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_TOTAL_SALARY
ON PLAYERS AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   UPDATE TEAM
   SET TEAM_TOTAL_SALARY = SUM(PLAY_SALARY) 
   FROM PLAYERS
   GROUP BY TEAM_NAME
   ORDER BY DESC
```

Comment: Why are you trying to store total team salary?  Calculate it on the fly as needed.

Comment: How do you know which team a player belongs to? That must be part of your trigger - something like `WHERE Players.TeamID = Team.TeamID` or something. Also: right now, you're updating **every** team every time something changes - you're not taking into account which players have been updated - you should also join on the `Inserted` pseudo table in the trigger somehow..

Comment: Thanks for the response. This may not be 100% ideal; it is for a university assignment. The issue is I have to use an existing database that I created prior to knowing we would have to do this. The trigger must adhere to strict guidelines, so although it may be easier to do other ways, I am stuck doing it this way. What I am struggling with, is how do I tell, SQL to SUM Players Salaries from Team 1, and insert it into the teams table under Team 1? Then do the same for TeamID 1-6? Would I simply use the where statement provided?